# UITableViewController data source from coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have found two ways of populating `UITableView` with data from coredata. One way is to use `NSFetchedResultsController` and implement the delegates for update `controller:didChangeSection`. Other way is to copy data from coredata to local array of Managed objects. Handle the updates on local array and saves the changes to managedcontex.
Both could be found on developer.apple.com.

I would like to hear pros and cons for each metod?

Thanks.

Comment: It is better to use NSFetchedResults controller, because your current view controller may not be the only one changing the data. It may happen in the background, or through some other view controller (for example, if you have a split view controller, you may be changing data related to a record in the master view controller, in the detail view controller). In those cases, you want your table to automatically reflect the changes. In extremely simple cases, where you are the only view controller in town, it may be easier the other way, but do it the right way and you will be happy.

Comment: You are right. I have forgot about the case when something could be updated from other "thread". Then, it seems, i should go the hard way and be up to date with my data :)

Comment: I will just answer this question then and you can accept it so that it can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use NSFetchedResults controller, because your current view controller may not be the only one changing the data. It may happen in the background, or through some other view controller (for example, if you have a split view controller, you may be changing data related to a record in the master view controller, in the detail view controller). In those cases, you want your table to automatically reflect the changes. In extremely simple cases, where you are the only view controller in town, it may be easier the other way, but do it the right way and you will be happy.